# Crawl Database disk almost out of capacity

Tags: 2010, crawling, database, fast-search, crawl

We have a huge SharePoint environment running which has one server running exclusive for crawling. 
The disk of this server only has 60gb left of space and we are planning in switching it for a larger one. My concern is losing all the indexes stored in this database and having to perform a full crawl again that would take about 10 days. 
I am mostly a developer who is starting in administration of SharePoint so I have almost no clue on what to do.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Would this work similar as a content database backup?

Thanks in advance.

edit: it's a physical server

edit2:

I found this guide and think that it could work out for me:

[Search indexer low disk space - Event 80 (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513130(v=office.15).aspx)

> 1. On the Central Administration page, click General Application Settings and in the Search section click Farm-wide Search Dashboard.
> 2. In the Search Service Application section, from the drop-down list select the search application that generated the event, and then click
>      Modify Topology.
> 3. On the Topology for Search Service Application page, click New, and then click Index Partition and Query Component.
> 4. In the Add query component dialog box, in the Query Server box, select the new application server and then click OK.
> 5. Click Apply Topology Changes. The changes are processed for the search application.
> 6. The topology splits the existing index partition into the new set of index partitions equally.

However I don't want to add a new application server. Could this be done in a similar way but adding a new index partition in the same web app?

Comment: Is this server running as a VM, or a physical server? If it's running as a VM, how about expanding the disk rather than throwing it away and creating a new one?

Comment: Forgot about this. Unfortunately it's a physical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk with your infrastructure team what procedures you have for it. But simplest is to attach larger disk duplicate the data and do logical switch of drives, then you can remove the old one. If you physical is using somekind of NAS (Network Access Storage) then the change is very easy.

Comment: How is the duplication of the data process exactly? I have done some content database backup and attachment trough powershell, is it something similar?

Comment: Also(I don't know if this is obvious), this server is our application server

Comment: In  sense it it similar but answer will depend on what infrastructure management software are you using. In my case we use EMC storage and we have no local disks so for me switch is easy requires only ticket to Storage team and they use EMC software to move, duplicate increase storage. Recently moved like that the index drive to SSD  (ExtremeIO) without doing anything on the Search server.

Comment: I you don't have any specific software for the storage management maybe some of the native options are good for you, have a look at this thread it discusses few options: http://serverfault.com/questions/370359/best-way-to-clone-my-windows-server-2008-r2 and here for some open source cloning options: https://www.cyberciti.biz/datacenter/5-awesome-open-source-cloning-software/